# Replace outdoor fixture where existing fixture larger than new one

Tags: electrical, lighting, outdoor

I have an outdoor light fixture for an "Outdoor Lantern" type light.  This fixture is recessed into the siding and has a crossbar-style mounting unit similar to [this](http://www.westwayelectricsupply.com/2100600-offset-crossbar.html?gclid=Cj0KEQiAqqO0BRDyo8mkv9y259EBEiQApVQD_UKFAbQaTV5j5CH-B1DhjQG40xgeAsmMqb_nK2yJ-YkaAjsU8P8HAQ).  I'd like to replace it with an exterior flood light to give the patio more light;  I've purchased an exterior flood light kit which includes a new weatherproof surface mount fixture box much like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Bell-4-in-Round-Weatherproof-Box-with-Five-1-2-in-Outlets-5361-1B/204208042).

Unfortunately, the hole drilled in the siding for the existing fixture is larger than the new surface-mount weatherproof box can cover.  I can't position the new box such that there is no exposed gap to the recessed existing fixture.

What's the best way to install the new light?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the situation, and dimensions of the old box?

Answer (score -1):

A tricky situation. If you can't get a piece of texture matching siding that you can paint to match, then I'd go with Aluminum flashing that you can easily paint & profile to the siding. You'll want to caulk & then screw or pop rivet the siding or flashing chunk to just under the siding's closest above rib to act as a roof for your patch, you're screwing the patch into just the siding & not the building or sheathing. First though, screw in an oval piece of plywood to the building's sheathing to fit in the old hole & fill-up the recess to mount your patch & new fixture to, center drilled-out for wiring. Use aluminum screws or rivets to avoid rusting, caulk your patch to the siding & caulk your fixture to your patch. Also, screw plugs with plumbing tape into the new box's unused holes, even if it's a bottom one.

Comment: I love it when boxes are sealed on the bottom, I find them all the time when the bkr starts tripping. code allows for a small hole in the bottom so it can drain if water gets in.

Comment: Yeah -- water *will* get in no matter what (sealed-in vapor can condense, and that's even true if you manage to hermetically seal the box somehow).  Gotta have a way out for it!